# Prayer of Manneseh, not in the protestant bible?

Tags: apocrypha

Why is the Prayer of Manasseh considered apocryphal by Jews, Catholics and Protestants?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayer_of_Manasseh

Comment: [What research have you done](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayer_of_Manasseh) on this topic?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast if I'm honest I'm just being lazy asking the question here.

Comment: David, if you do a bit more research and still have some questions, you can edit the question to be more precise on what is puzzling you and get a good, scoped answer.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast understood

Comment: It actually was included in the original [1611 King James Bible](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/1611_Prayer-of-Manasseh-Chapter-1/).  It was taken out of it in 1885.

Comment: As far as the latter two denominations are concerned, it is due to the tremendous influence exercised by [Saint Jerome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerome) on Western, Latin-speaking Christianity. As far as traditional Judaism is concerned, it is because the [Greek Septuagint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint) was a product of [Hellenistic Judaism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellenistic_Judaism), rather than Judaism proper, which, until this day, employs the [Masoretic Text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text).

Answer (score 1):

The prayer departs from Christian teaching in that it says men such as Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob did not need to repent because they “did not sin” (verse 8). This runs counter to the clear teaching of Scripture that all have sinned (Romans 3:10-12; Romans 3:21-26). The righteousness of Abraham was a product of his faith in God and was not anything inherent in him (Romans 4:3; Philippians 3:8-9).

https://www.gotquestions.org/Prayer-of-Manasseh.html

Comment: This explanation is completely bogus.  The word in the Septuagint for "sin" in this particular verse is ἁμαρτάνω, which can also simply mean to do wrong.   Further, if Manasseh was removed on this basis alone, then the Gospel of John should have been removed as well because Christ said in 9:3 than neither the blind man nor his parents had sinned.   I think we need some source more authoritative than "gotquestions.org" here.

Comment: @user33515  a fine and fair point Sir! I have revoked my own accepted answer...please feel free to post an answer.

Comment: See Matthew 9:13; Mark 2:17; Luke 5:32.